# How to transform an url to other?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to transform this url's :

- localhost:8080/codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/users/1
- localhost:8080/codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/users

to

- localhost:8080/codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/api2.php?rquest=users&id=$1
- localhost:8080/codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/api2.php?rquest=users

in the same .htacces

I try:

```
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s

RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/api2.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule "^users/([0-9]+)/$" /codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/api2.php?rquest=users&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

but don't work.

Can any one help to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you are not actually including the "#", right?

Comment: Add a `RewriteEngine on` _before_ all rewriting rules. Also you have to enbable consideration of `.htaccess` style files at all in the http server configuration. Then make requests and check the log file for errors.

Comment: jejeje right, without # don't work.

Comment: @arkascha , I have all of this, but don't work . thanks.

Comment: Where is the .htaccess including the directives located in your directory hierarchy?

Comment: What does "don't work" mean here? nothing happens? Some incorrect rewriting happens? An error is raised? The universe implodes?

Comment: @arkascha The universe imploded with your sarcasm...

Comment: Really make sure the `.htaccess` style file is actually interpreted. Easiest to do this is to implement a definite syntax error in there. If that does _not_ result in an error in your http servers error log file, then the file simply is not used.

Comment: @arkascha it works because if I write  localhost:8080/codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/users it works , but i need to work with booth examples.

Comment: @Amarnasan .htaccess is in localhost:8080/codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest

Comment: So you mean one of the rules actually _does_ work? Why don't you say so in the question? That is a totally different situation! (sorry, that is frustrating, I am out)

Comment: So, what is the URL that is ACTUALLY NOT working?

Comment: @arkascha sorry, yes, if i put only localhost:8080/codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/users  with   
 RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/api2.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

Works, but when i put both the second one don't work

Comment: @Amarnasan this don't work 
localhost:8080/codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/api2.php?rquest=users&id=$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the "?" after the "/" in the seconde rule. Try this:

```
RewriteRule "^users/([0-9]+)/?$" /codeschoolangular/codeschoolangular/ApiRest/api2.php?rquest=users&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```